# Assigning input field's value to background-image of a div / duplicated content

Tags: jquery

I use the code below to change `background-image` of a div from the input field's value which works fine:

```
$(".ImageUrl").blur(function(){
    $(".Image").css("background-image", "url("+$(this).val()+")");
});

<div class="wrap">
    <section>
        <input class="ImageUrl"/>
        <div class="Image"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Not suprisingly, when a duplicate `.wrap` div is added & an url is typed, it changes both divs' backgrounds as in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/adige72/tKS6j/

What i want is that each "wrap" works as if there is only one "wrap".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the sibling `.Image`

```
$(".ImageUrl").blur(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".Image").css("background-image", "url("+$(this).val()+")");
});
```

**EDIT**

The above assumes that when you say, *"Not suprisingly, when a duplicate div is added"* you mean a duplicate `.wrap` div.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use an unique ID instead of a class name for your selector, or change your selector to select only the first element:

```
$(".ImageUrl").eq(0).....
```